# Implementing Asp.NetCore Identity Authentication in Blazor App That Has Existing Roles and Users

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have been tasked with implementing authentication from an SQL Server database that already has dbo.AspNetUsers, dbo.AspNetRoles, dbo.AspNetUserClaims, dbo.AspNetUserLogins, dbo.AspNetUserRoles all created- I will be using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` library.

I have my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "IdentityDataContextConnection": "Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Database=xx_xx;User id=xxx;Password='xxxxx';"
  }
}
```

And my `Program.cs`

```
using Ts.UIs.ClusterSettings.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Ts.UIs.ClusterSettings.Areas.Identity.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDataContextConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Everytime I try to login with username and password, it tells me that I have had an invalid login attempt. This is the log:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedUserName_0='?' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
      WHERE [a].[NormalizedUserName] = @__normalizedUserName_0
```

It looks like `NormalizedUserName` in the table is set to NULL for all users, so not sure if that affects anything.

How do I implement and get the authentication to work here?